# password field to install programs using gdebi is disabled

Tags: password, gdebi

I was trying to install a .deb file in Ubuntu 17.10 using gdebi but the password field is disabled.

Also cannot open using `gksudo` the same password prompt which I cannot type the password.

[image: when i try to install using gdebi]

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with `gksudo` or even your theme; From what I can see in your screenshot you are getting "Incorrect password" message, remember that you should enter your own user's password not the `root`, both the `gksu` and `gksudo` work in `--sudo-mode` cause `root` user is disabled in Ubuntu by default.

Anyway you can always run `gdebi` from terminal:

```
sudo gdebi /path/to/your/package.deb
```

It should work for you.

You can also try this one for graphical `gdebi` installer:

```
sudo -H gdebi-gtk /path/to/your/package.deb
```

Another option is to use `pkexec` to run `gdebi-gtk`:

```
pkexec gdebi-gtk /path/to/your/package.deb
```

You can even use `apt` to install your `deb` package:

```
sudo apt install /path/to/your/package.deb
```

---

`gdebi` will install your desired package from terminal, and `gdebi-gtk` will show a GUI and you can use "Install package" option as always you do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually installed it using terminal.
But still i have to solve the issue. 

I cannot type any password there. 

// getting "Incorrect password" message, // got it when i press ok button without typing any password

Comment: Have you tried running `gksudo` with other commands? e.g: `gksudo ls`?

Comment: yes its also giving the same password prompt

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps however give it a shot: `dpkg-reconfigure gksu`

Comment: No change. Still same

Comment: I have the same problem on debian testing. With me the password I type get's captured by the underlying program, and I don't see the caret at all.

Answer (score 0):

if you upgraded to ubuntu 18.04, do this:
create this file `/usr/local/bin/gdebi-gtk-pkexec`
with this contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkexec "/usr/bin/gdebi-gtk" "$@"
```

right click on a .deb file, show properties, set default open with to `/usr/local/bin/gdebi-gtk-pkexec`

Comment: if it worked for 17.10 say it, but I guess u already upgraded.