# gdebi installer exits without installing the .deb file in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, 18.04, gdebi

I have `gdebi` set as the default application to install .deb files. This way, I can just double-click on a .deb file and the `gdebi` installer will do the rest.

It seems that since 17.10, or one of its updates, this no longer works. I double-click on a .deb file, `gdebi` launches, showing the appropriate .deb file information, I click INSTALL, and `gdebi` just exits.

I have reinstalled all of the `gdebi` software components. No change.

However, in `terminal`, I type `sudo gdebi some_filename.deb`, it all works fine.

Any idea why the GUI doesn't work any more? I'm using xorg, not wayland.

**Update #1**: I have two machines with this problem. Both were upgrades to 17.10.

**Update #2**: If I manually open `gdebi` and manually select the .deb file to install, it all works fine.

**Update #3**: If I show properties of any .deb file, and try to change the "Open With" application, GDebi doesn't show up in the list of available applications.

**Final Update**: Late postnote... `gdebi` has problems in 18.xx too. It won't install .deb files when you double-click them... **if they're on the desktop**... it never asks for admin password. Anywhere else, it works as it should.

Comment: Try to switch to Xorg session.

Comment: @N0rbert good suggestion. I was already using xorg, and updated my question to include that info.

Comment: On my 17.10 MATE it works on Xorg. I have no ideas.

Comment: @heynnema Do you have `gksu` installed (and updated)?

Comment: @pomsky good suggestion. Yes, `gksu` is installed and current.

Comment: **Late postnote**... gdebi has problems in 18.xx too. It won't install .deb files if they're on the desktop,.. it never asks for admin password. Anywhere else, it works as it should. I wonder if this problem is an early version of the problem.

Comment: try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1230951/46437 works well on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

### `gdebi` works in a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10

`gdebi` (installed from the Ubuntu repo) works for me in a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 in text mode when started from a terminal window (like it works for you), but it works also in graphics mode even with Wayland after

```
xhost +si:localuser:root
```

as illustrated with the following screenshot

[image]

I think your problem is caused by something left from the previous version after the `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think that you're correct about left-overs from 17.04.

Comment: @heynnema, By the way, I have seen several issues, that occur in systems, that are upgraded from previous versions to Ubuntu 17.10. I am afraid that too many things have changed from the previous version for the `do-release-upgrade` to succeed in this case. In other words, I would recommend a fresh install ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From what you wrote, it seems that `gdebi` cannot change to root mode after you press <kbd>Install</kbd>. In the terminal you are using sudo and it starts in root mode from the beginning. I'm pretty sure that if you start `gdebi` or modify its launcher to use `gksu gdebi` it will work fine.

Comment: `gdebi-gtk` already uses pkexec in internals.

Comment: gdebi.desktop shows `Exec=gdebi-gtk`, and both `gdebi` and `gdebi-gtk` are root:root.